# Why is my Databinding not reacting to a PropertyChange?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to bind my DataTrigger to a `bool` Property but for some reason, it doesnt wanna change values. It starts off as false, and then when I select a RadioButton it turns true but the value doesnt update my DataTrigger.
I tried binding the `Text` property of a TextBox to see what the value was and if it changes but it doesnt.
[Here is a video showing how it behaves](https://streamable.com/axdgb)

As you can see when I debug it turns true but doesnt update the `Text` property
When you select an item it should Turn false and then turn back to true because you select a new RadioButton.
That however is not the case.

**The main issue**
I am trying to bind my DataTrigger

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=EntryItemViewModel.IsEntrySelected}" Value="True">
```

to my `IsEntrySelected` but it never reads the value as true UNLESS I explicitly set it to true in the constructor

```
public EntryItemViewModel()
        {
            IsEntrySelected = true;
        }
```

MainWindows.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new EntryItemListViewModel();
    }
}
```

And the MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>

        <!-- Animation -->
        <Grid.Resources>
            <system:Double x:Key="AddEntrySlideOffset">300</system:Double>
            <Storyboard x:Key="AddEntrySlideRight">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                 From="0" To="{StaticResource AddEntrySlideOffset}"
                                 Duration="0:0:0.2" />
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="AddEntrySlideLeft">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                 From="{StaticResource AddEntrySlideOffset}" To="0"
                                 Duration="0:0:0.2" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>


        <Grid Width="150"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <local:EntryItemListUserControl x:Name="MyUserControl"/>
        </Grid>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding EntryItemViewModel.IsEntrySelected}"
                 Width="200"
                 Height="25"/>

        <StackPanel Height="50"
                    Width="50"
                    Background="Gainsboro" Margin="375,128,367,241">
            <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=EntryItemViewModel.IsEntrySelected}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AddEntrySlideRight}" />
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AddEntrySlideLeft}" />
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>


            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform />
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

EntryItemUserControl.xaml

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding EntryItem}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton Grid.Column="0"
                                 GroupName="Content"
                                 Content="{Binding Title}"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding IsEntrySelected}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

EntryItemListViewModel.cs

```
public class EntryItemListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<EntryItemViewModel> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<EntryItemViewModel>();
        public EntryItemViewModel EntryItemViewModel { get; set; }  = new EntryItemViewModel();

        public EntryItemListViewModel()
        {
            Items.Add(new EntryItemViewModel { Title = "Hello World" });
            Items.Add(new EntryItemViewModel { Title = "Hello World" });
            Items.Add(new EntryItemViewModel { Title = "Hello World" });
            Items.Add(new EntryItemViewModel { Title = "Hello World" });
        }

        private EntryItemViewModel _entryItem;

        public EntryItemViewModel EntryItem
        {
            get { return _entryItem; }
            set
            {
                _entryItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EntryItem));
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And finally EntryItemViewModel.cs

```
public class EntryItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _title;

        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set
            {
                _title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }

        private bool _isSelected;

        public bool IsEntrySelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsEntrySelected");
            }
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: So where are how are you setting the property when it doesn't work...?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you solve the problem.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=EntryItemViewModel.IsEntrySelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention how you are setting the source property when it doesn't work. But you have one `EntryItemViewModel` property and another `EntryItem` property in your `EntryItemListViewModel`. Setting the `IsEntrySelected` property of the `EntryItemViewModel` should work.

You can confirm this by for example handling the `MouseLeftButtonDown` for the `StackPanel` in the view:

```
private void StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = DataContext as EntryItemListViewModel;
    vm.EntryItemViewModel.IsEntrySelected = true;
}
```

Comment: @MarkDenom: Did you try this or what happened?